# Testing Highcharts with selenium

Tags: testing, selenium-rc, highcharts

Is it possible to test highcharts in a webpage using Selenium? I am currently using Selenium-rc and perl to test a webpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can run javascript to read data and inject it to html tag then read the html tag value:

```
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;       
executor.executeScript("var y = Highcharts.charts[0].series[0].data[0].y;$('body').append('<span id=\"testTag\">'+y+'</span>');");
WebElement y = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='testTag']"))
```

Answer (score 0):

firefox render highcharts js and result to svg code.the svg code is not testable. so i suggest add test flag. when test phase, you can print two-dimensional surface.selenium can easy extact table node and data.